# Fluent Validation unit testing SetValidator with a When clause

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to unit test the ability to set child validator depending on a property value.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property2)
    .SetValidator(new Property2Validator())
    .When(x => x.Property1 == 1);
```

In my unit test I have the following assertion

```
validatorUnderTest.ShouldHaveChildValidator(x => x.Property2, typeof(Property2Validator));
```

However this always fail as the validator is only attached whilst the validation is taking place. If I remove the 'When' clause it picks it up fine.

Comment: Do you have any other rules defined for Property2?

Comment: @GiovanniRomio Nope that is literally all I have in there.

Comment: I have the same question. Even after you call 'Validate' there is no validator attached still...